# Error when restarting mysql

Tags: mysql

i run: `sudo service mysql restart` and i get this:

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

when i run `systemctl status mysql.service` i get:

```
Oct 01 21:27:16 matthewserver systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Oct 01 21:27:17 matthewserver systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Oct 01 21:27:17 matthewserver systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Oct 01 21:27:17 matthewserver systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Oct 01 21:27:17 matthewserver systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Oct 01 21:27:17 matthewserver systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 01 21:27:17 matthewserver systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Oct 01 21:27:25 matthewserver systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Oct 01 21:27:25 matthewserver systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 01 21:27:25 matthewserver systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

why does this come up, how can i fix it?

Comment: Check `/var/log/mysql/error.log`

Comment: all i found was `Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 181002 14:57:35
2018-10-02T14:57:37.284023Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 2595367
2018-10-02T14:57:37.287271Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2018-10-02T14:57:37.287299Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2018-10-02T14:57:37.287314Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
`